# Win form application not updating label

Tags: c#

I am currently writing an application in C# that processes some XML among other things. Some of the XML docs can be quite big so I added in a label to show the user that characters are still being processed and that the application is still running.

The actual XML building is being run in a different thread but the XMLInProg and charsProcessed are class variables which the main thread can see and use them to update the GUI.

For some strange reason, I can only get the status label to update whenever I get a messagebox to popup along with the update. Can anyone explain why?

Thanks.

This does not work...

```
while (XMLInProg)
        {
            status.Text = "Building XML... " + charsProcessed + " characters processed";
        }
```

But this will work

```
 while (XMLInProg)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Works now");
            status.Text = "Building XML... " + charsProcessed + " characters processed";
        }
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realise that would happen. I assumed since the text was being updated in the loop it would update it before the next iteration.

Comment: "The actual XML building is being run in a different thread" ...but I suspect that the `while` loop shown is in the main UI thread polling for the other thread to complete?  If so, that kinda negates the whole point of using another thread in the first place.

Comment: The XML starts being built at an earlier stage. The user will only have to wait for it to finish if they get to the stage where its needed before its been fully created.

Comment: Doesn't really matter when it was started.  If you've got a polling loop like that in your main UI thread it's pretty much never the right way to go about it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call the refresh method on the label (within the loop):

```
status.Refresh()
```

Comment: Yeah this does work i assume its now forcing the label to update before it continues onto the next iteration.

Comment: @FearghalConn well if this is the answer then accept it

Comment: Couldn't accept it before now, you need to wait a period of time before you can accept an answer.